# How do I set an instance with a route in my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using a nested routes in rails and I want to define  `@hotel` in my booking controller.

Where `:booking` belongs_to `:hotel`.

```
@hotel = Hotel.find(params[:id])
```

But the result couldn't find the "hotel"

Though I clicked on the

```
<%= link_to 'Book Now', new_booking_path, :hotel_id => @ hotel.id %>
```

From my hotel show page....

Comment: if you could add more details to your question, it might help people answer better.

Comment: try `<%= link_to 'Book Now', new_booking_path(:hotel_id => @hotel.id) %>`. if that doesn't work, make sure your route is correct. You mentioned nested routes, so you might need to use something like `new_hotel_booking_path`. Posting your routes might help us answer better.

Comment: Also you appear to have a space between `@` and `hotel.id`.

Comment: @forthowin it helps but crashes when I get to the controller. It displays nomethod error 'bookings'

Comment: Like I said, posting your controller and route will help us better answer you.